# Color and font style of xlabel in matplotlib in chrome on Ubuntu not as expected in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In the [tensorflow basic classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification), the method `plot_image` is called to render a single image from the dataset, with a label showing its predicted class and actual class. The method assigns color blue if `predicted_class == actual_class` and red otherwise to the label.

It works as expected when I look at the image by itself.

However,  when the image is rendered as output in a jupyter notebook or a web page generated from such a jupyter notebook, in chrome on Ubuntu, the label colors do not look blue and red, but instead, look like purple and turquoise respectively. Also, the wrong prediction seems to use a bolder font than the right prediction. I don't see any code that makes the font bolder.

What is making this label show a different color and boldness than the code?

The link shows the difference in color for the correct prediction and wrong prediction.

The code for plot_image from the same page is reproduced below:

```
def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
  predictions_array, true_label, img = predictions_array[i], true_label[i], img[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])

  plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
  if predicted_label == true_label:
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = 'red'

  plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                                100*np.max(predictions_array),
                                class_names[true_label]),
                                color=color)
```

Comment: Could you share a picture how this looks like for you? It's kind of hard to believe that specifying `color="blue"` would result in something not blue.

Comment: Actually this is happening only in chrome on Ubuntu. I just opened the link on my phone and it looks fine.

Comment: I think it may be because of the night light feature in Ubuntu. I turned it off completely, but it does seem to have messed up the colors on my machine.